# Entity Framework hangs when using async calls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am new to using async and this seems to elude me on what the cause or issue is, when I attempt to load the webpage the async call seems to hang and the page is never loaded. Is my implementation wrong here?

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var model = _partyAddOnService.Get().Result.Select(x => new AddOnModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        AddOnType = x.AddOnType,
        Description = x.Description,
        Name = x.Name,
        Price = x.Price
    });

    return View(model);
}
```

SERVICE

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AddOn>> Get()
{
    return await _repository.GetAsync();
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync()
{
    return await Context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

UPDATE:

I tried this as well and it still hangs...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var model = _partyAddOnService.Get();
    return View();
}
```

*** When debugging and looking at the Task status it says "Waiting for activation"

Also tried using the ConfigureAwait method as the article suggested. (see James comment below)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<AddOn>> Get()
{
    return await _repository.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Your code is [deadlocking](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Why are you using async if you want to synchronously obtain the result of the call? `Result` blocks.

Comment: I imagine the deadlocking is my controller? Not sure how to fix though.

Comment: @usr It's all new to me, what I am trying to do is simply make my EF calls async to improve performance. I figured my controller is the issue but I don't know how to fix it. Tried using .ConfigureAwait(false) on my service and it made no difference.

Comment: @yycdev "*not sure how to fix though*" - read the article, it explains how you resolve the issue.

Comment: @James - I did read it. :) More than once actually... I understand why the deadlocking is happening now and I did try the suggested method there but it still hangs. Thanks for sharing the article, I've bookmarked it as it explains a lot and I'll likely be falling back on it again in the future.

Comment: @yycdev post the code you have tried which is still hanging.

Comment: @yycdev async will slightly lower performance in low-concurrency scenarios. It increases performance only in high-concurrency workloads. Before using async a) understand how it works and b) how to use it.

Comment: @usr yeah the more I've been reading about it the more I realize this whole thing is a waste of time and effort. I'll remove it and simply just call the database synchronously. I don't have any methods that rely on multiple calls to the database, EF returns my data with children based on FK automatically so I don't need to call multiple times. I was just trying to be proactive in my code architecture. Darn over-eager junior developer syndrome. Thanks for the help (everyone)

Comment: @yycdev a smart choice.

Comment: I modified the code in my repository, so I have a Get and a GetAsync method... just in case ;) never know! lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent deadlocks, just use `async` all the way up. You're already using it in your service and repository, so just add it to your controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var model = (await _partyAddOnService.Get()).Select(x => new AddOnModel()
  {
    Id = x.Id,
    AddOnType = x.AddOnType,
    Description = x.Description,
    Name = x.Name,
    Price = x.Price
  });

  return View(model);
}
```

I also recommend that you change your async methods to end in `Async`, to follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I.e., `Get` should be `GetAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

You are causing a deadlock, because you didn't implement the async-await pattern all the way up. Also use .ConfigureAwait(false) on the lowest level.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{

    var model = await _partyAddOnService.Get().Result.Select(x => new AddOnModel()
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        AddOnType = x.AddOnType,
        Description = x.Description,
        Name = x.Name,
        Price = x.Price
    });

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? As someone who is trying to learn and understand async I am curious to know if there is something perhaps if I should know something not to do here?

Comment: Using async IO and then blocking defeats the point and gets you the worst of both worlds. @yycdev for that reason your own code doesn't make sense either.